# Unable to paste an image into the TinyMCE editor in Internet Explorer 11. Is this expected behaviour?

Tags: javascript, tinymce, internet-explorer-11

I am using tinyMCE 4. What I am doing is to copy an image from a folder on my desktop and paste it into the tinyMCE editor (using Ctrl-V). This does not seem to work on IE11 and I have noticed that the debugger does not hit the paste_preprocess event (which I have set up) either. It works in Chrome and Firefox though. However I have found that snipping and pasting an image into the editor in IE11 does work. Is this just not supported in IE11 or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

This is not expected behavior. TinyMCE supports pasting images in IE11. You can try the [default fiddle](https://fiddle.tiny.cloud/qOhaab) to check if it works for you.

Also, review the browser settings. IE could close clipboard access completely. Go to *Internet Options > Security > Internet zone > Custom Level > (see at the bottom) > Allow programmatic clipboard access* and check if there are any restrictions.

Comment: I tried the same in a sample app that does not have tinyMCE. What I did was to paste an image into a div in IE11 and check if the paste event was run but the paste event did not get triggered.